# Data Cleaning in R: remove test customer names

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am handling customer data that has customer first and last name. I want to clean the names of any random keystrokes. Test accounts are jumbled in the data-set and have junk names. For example in the below data I want to remove customers 2,5,9,10,12 etc. I would appreciate your help.

```
 Customer Id    FirstName   LastName
1   MARY    MEYER
2   GFRTYUIO    UHBVYY
3   CHARLES BEAL
4   MARNI   MONTANEZ
5   GDTDTTD DTTHDTHTHTHD
6   TIFFANY BAYLESS
7   CATHRYN JONES
8   TINA    CUNNINGHAM
9   FGCYFCGCGFC FGCGFCHGHG
10  ADDHJSDLG   DHGAHG
11  WALTER  FINN
12  GFCTFCGCFGC CG GFCGFCGFCGF
13  ASDASDASD   AASDASDASD
14  TYKTYKYTKTY YTKTYKTYK
15  HFHFHF  HAVE
16  REBECCA CROSSWHITE
17  GHSGHG  HGASGH
18  JESSICA TREMBLEY
19  GFRTYUIO    UHBVYY
20  HUBHGBUHBUH YTVYVFYVYFFV
21  HEATHER WYRICK
22  JASON   SPLICHAL
23  RUSTY   OWENS
24  DUSTIN  WILLIAMS
25  GFCGFCFGCGFC    GRCGFXFGDGF
26  QWQWQW  QWQWWW
27  LIWNDVLIHWDV    LIAENVLIHEAV
28  DARLENE SHORTRIDGE
29  BETH    HDHDHDH
30  ROBERT  SHIELDS
31  GHERDHBXFH  DFHFDHDFH
32  ACE TESSSSSRT
33  ALLISON AWTREY
34  UYGUGVHGVGHVG   HGHGVUYYU
35  HCJHV   FHJSEFHSIEHF
```

Comment: What's the rule for "random keystrokes"?

Comment: I am afraid there is no rule. Test accounts were created by randomly punching keyboard keys for the first and last name. Had there been a pattern, it would have been so easy. Thanks for asking clarification.

Comment: A start would be using the `hunspell` library: `library(hunspell);
df$flag <- hunspell_check(df$FirstName) & hunspell_check(df$LastName)` although it's not perfect (which is why I created a flag).  I think that if a name is NOT flagged then you can be quite certain it's valid. However, you have cases like row 4 'Marni Montanez` which appears to be valid but is flagged.

Comment: Then your objective is to find a database of  names (most common?) and subset your data according it. It's relatively easy in R. However, finding such database is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I think this could be a great start, I will check more functionality of hunspell. Thanks

Comment: @PoGibas the rule for random keystrokes is: same keyboard letters pushed several times, therefore, low variability of letters and high average frequency.

Comment: @Seymour `FINN` has double `N` - is this random? How do you measure variability?

Comment: The name is walter finn, not just finn. Variability is the number of unique letters divided the total string length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can calculate variability strength of full name (combine FirstName and LastName) by calculating length of unique letters in full name divided by total number of characters in the full name. Then, just remove the names that has low variability strength. This means that you are removing the names that has a high frequency of same random keystrokes resulting in low variability strength.

I did this using `charToRaw` function because it very faster and using `dplyr` library, as below:

```
# Building Test Data
df <- data.frame(CustomerId = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
          FirstName = c("MARY", "FGCYFCGCGFC", "GFCTFCGCFGC", "ASDASDASD", "GDTDTTD", "WALTER", "GFCTFCGCFGC"),
          LastName = c("MEYER", "FGCGFCHGHG", "GFCGFCGFCGF", "AASDASDASD", "DTTHDTHTHTHD", "FINN", "CG GFCGFCGFCGF"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#test data: df
#   CustomerId    FirstName         LastName
#1         1           MARY            MEYER
#2         2    FGCYFCGCGFC       FGCGFCHGHG
#3         3    GFCTFCGCFGC      GFCGFCGFCGF
#4         4      ASDASDASD       AASDASDASD
#5         5        GDTDTTD     DTTHDTHTHTHD
#6         6         WALTER             FINN
#7         7    GFCTFCGCFGC   CG GFCGFCGFCGF

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  ## Combining FirstName and LastName
  mutate(FullName = paste(FirstName, gsub(" ", "", LastName, fixed = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(FullName) %>%
  ## Calculating variability strength for each full name
  mutate(Variability = length(unique(as.integer(charToRaw(FullName))))/nchar(FullName))%>%
  ## Filtering full name, I set above or equal to 0.4 (You can change this)
  ## Meaning we are keeping full name that has variability strength greater than or equal to 0.40
  filter(Variability >= 0.40)


# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   FullName [2]
# CustomerId FirstName LastName    FullName   Variability
#  <dbl>     <chr>      <chr>        <chr>        <dbl>
#1   1        MARY      MEYER     MARY MEYER    0.6000000
#2   6      WALTER      FINN     WALTER FINN    0.9090909
```

Comment: Aren't you include whitespace in `FullName` when calculating variability?

Comment: Yes, but then each full name has a one whitespace. So, overall, it does not matter.

Comment: Check row 12 in OPs example - what if random keystroke was a space?

Comment: Thanks, I removed the whitespace in last name using `gsub`. I also added row 12 example in test data.

Comment: @Santosh thank you for writing the code of my answer. However, a crucial component is missing which is the average frequency of the letters in the ’strname’. This is extremely important because it allows a more delicate and sound anomaly detection, especially, it highlight the very few cases that are ambiguous and need some manual investigation. Thank you

Comment: @Seymour My code is about filtering based on variability strength as you mentioned in your answer. However, it does not create a column with flags. Feel free to modify my code and include your average frequency metric and create columns with flags. I think that would be different answer which you can add as another answer to this question of OP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you'd need a solid definition of improbable names, and that is not really related to R. Anyway, I suggest you go by the first names and remove all those names that are not plausible. As a source of plausible first names or positive list, you could use e.g. [SSA Baby Name Database](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html). This should work reasonably well to filter out English first names. If you have more location specific needs for first names, just look online for other baby name databases and try to scrape them as a positive list.

Once you have them in a vector named `positiveNames`, filter out all non-positive names like this:

```
data_new <- data_original[!data_original$firstName %in% positiveNames,]
```

Comment: I tried similar kind of approach and used SSA database, issue it over cleans. My data set has names from geographies all across world. This may not be specific to R but on a macro sense I am looking for a logic that can identify improbable names.  Using SSA, half of the names are flagged as non-positive.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is the following:

1) Merge `FirstName` and `LastName` into a single string, `strname`.
Then, count the number of letters for each `strname`.

2) At this point, we find that for real names, like "MARNIMONTANEZ", are composed of two 'M'; two 'A'; one 'R'; one 'I'; three 'N'; one 'O'; one 'T'.
And we find that fake names, like "GFCTFCGCFGCCGGFCGFCGFCGF", are composed of six 'G'; five 'F'; 8 'C'.

3) The pattern to distinguish real names from fake names becomes clear:

- real names are characterized by a more variety of letters. We can measure this by creating a variable `check_real` computed as: `number of unique letters / total string length`
- fake names are characterized by few letters repeated several times. We can measure this by creating a variable `check_fake` computed as: `average frequency of each letter`

4) Finally, we just have to define a threshold to identify an anomaly for both variable. In the cases where these threshold are triggered, a `flag_real` and a `flag_fake` appears.

- if  `flag_real == 1 & flag_fake == 0`, the name is real
- if  `flag_real == 0 & flag_fake == 1`, the name is fake
- In the rare cases when the two flags agrees (i.e. `flag_real == 1 & flag_fake == 1`), you have to investigate the record manually to optimize the threshold.

Comment: This is amazing. I was hoping to find something on these line. Let me give it a try. I guess key here is to find a right threshold. I will update what I find. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that check_real and check_fake variables are just two examples, I am sure we can generate even more meaningful or discriminative variables to express whether a name is real or fake.  
Furthermore, since nowadays we are in a bigdata world, a nicer approach can combine my idea with @tophcito idea of integrating your data with an external open data source.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to combine the suggestions in the below code. Thanks everyone for the help.

```
# load required libraries 
library(hunspell)
library(dplyr)
# read data in dataframe df
df<-data.frame(CustomerId = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8), 
               FirstName = c("MARY"," ALBERT SAM", "FGCYFCGCGFC", "GFCTFCGCFGC", "ASDASDASD", "GDTDTTD", "WALTER", "GFCTFCGCFGC"),
               LastName = c("MEYER","TEST", "FGCGFCHGHG", "GFCGFCGFCGF", "AASDASDASD", "DTTHDTHTHTHD", "FINN", "CG GFCGFCGFCGF"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Keep unique names
df<-distinct(df,FirstName, LastName, .keep_all = TRUE)
# Spell check using hunspel
df$flag <- hunspell_check(df$FirstName) | hunspell_check(as.character(df$LastName))
# remove middle names
df$FirstNameOnly<-gsub(" .*","",df$FirstName)

# SSA name data using https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/names.zip
# unzip files in folder named names
files<-list.files("/names",pattern="*.txt")
ssa_names<- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, 
                          col.names = c("Name","Gender","Frequency"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
# Change SSA names to uppercase
ssa_names$Name <- toupper(ssa_names$Name)
# Flad for SSA names
df$flag_SSA<-ifelse(df$FirstNameOnly %in% ssa_names$Name,TRUE,FALSE)
rm(ssa_names)
# remove spaces and concatenate first name and last name
df$strname<-gsub(" ","",paste(df$FirstName,df$LastName, sep = ""))
# Name string length
df$len<-nchar(df$strname)

# Unique string length
for(n in 1:nrow(df))
{
  df$ulen[n]<-length(unique(strsplit(df$strname[n], "")[[1]]))
}

# Ratio variable for unique string length over total string length 
df$ratio<-ifelse(df$len==0,0,df$ulen/df$len)
# Histogram to determine cutoff ratio
hist(df$ratio)
test<-df[df$ratio<.4 & df$flag_SSA==FALSE & df$flag==FALSE,]
```